# Converting NSString to NSDate then sorting by NSDate returning null

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsstring, nsdate

within my application I am parsing in dates as strings from an RSS feed and attempting to sort them by the date. When I do a standard sortDescriptor on the strings, it sorts fine, but because the format is "DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS" it is being sorted by the day rather than the whole date, so my list is not in chronological order.

I am therefore attempting to convert the date string parsed from the RSS into an NSDate and then sort by the date. However, when I'm doing this it returns null. Can anyone specify where I'm going wrong?

```
        // Loop through XML data
    [rxml iterate:@"channel" usingBlock:^(RXMLElement *supportElement) {
        [supportElement iterate:@"item" usingBlock:^(RXMLElement *repElement) {

            // Assign element to string
            NSString *title = [repElement child:@"title"].text;
            NSString *description = [repElement child:@"description"].text;
            NSString *imageurl = [repElement child:@"image"].text;
            NSString *mystartDate = [repElement child:@"start_date"].text;
            NSString *myendDate = [repElement child:@"end_date"].text;


            // DESCRIPTION FORMATTING
            description = [customStringParser parseHTML:description];
            description = [customStringParser parseLinesMultiple:description];
            description = [customStringParser removeSocialSignifiers:description];
            currentFeed.description = description;

            // DATE FORMATTING

            NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS"];
            [dateFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehaviorDefault];
            NSDate *startDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:mystartDate];
            NSDate *endDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:myendDate];

            currentFeed.startDate = startDate;
            currentFeed.endDate = endDate;


            NSLog(@"%@", startDate);
            NSLog(@"%@", endDate);


            // Add a new object to the feeds array
            [eventsFeeds addObject:currentFeed];
        }];
        [loadingView removeFromSuperview];
        [self.loadingIndicator stopAnimating];


        //sort array
        NSSortDescriptor *sortByDate = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"startDate" ascending:NO];
        [eventsFeeds sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortByDate]];
```

I also then believe I may have to convert the NSDate back to a string so that it can be printed within my detailTextLabel on the view controller, is this correct? Thanks.

Comment: can you please post a example date string from the RSS Feed source?

Comment: "01 Jan 2013" does not match "DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS"

Comment: Sorry, made a slight mistake in my question. From the RSS Feed source it comes in as DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS. I have some code in the app that converts it to dd MMM yy but I've removed that for now.

Comment: Your date format is woefully incorrect.

Comment: (You're asking for day-of-year/month/year for "week of year" calendar, hour:month:hundredths of a second. See http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns.)

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist - "DD MMM YYYY" is nowhere near correct.

Comment: @HotLicks I was confused by the OP using capital letters everywhere. Of course I meant that "01 Jan 2013" looked more like "dd MMM yyyy" (and not "DD MMM YYYY"). However the OP removed "01 Jan 2013" from the question so I'm not sure the comment is relevant anymore.

Comment: Net-net is to consult the above-referenced spec, and observe *very carefully* capitalizations and number of repeat characters as specified in the spec.  (Many people get bit by "YYYY", eg.  That's hardly ever correct.)

Answer (score 0):

You should change:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS"];
```

to

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *arr = [folderContent sortedArrayUsingFunction:dateSort context:nil];



//The date sort function



NSComparisonResult dateSort(NSString *s1, NSString *s2, void *context) {


NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];

NSDate *d1 = [formatter dateFromString:[s1 substringFromIndex:[s1 length]-19]];
NSDate *d2 = [formatter dateFromString:[s2 substringFromIndex:[s2 length]-19]]; 

//  return [d1 compare:d2]; // ascending order
return [d2 compare:d1]; // descending order
 }
```